# Summarizing Data by Count of Variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to rearrange my data to summarize as a specific format.

Data to summarize and rearrange:

```
type    user
phone   A
phone   B
email   A
email   A
phone   B
phone   A
```

Format desired:

```
type    A   B
phone   2   2
email   2   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We get the frequency with `count` and `spread` from 'long' to 'wide'

```
library(tidyverse)
count(df1, type, user) %>%
   spread(user, n, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  type      A     B
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 email     2     0
#2 phone     2     2
```

---

Or using `table` from `base R`

```
table(df1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(type = c("phone", "phone", "email", "email", "phone", 
 "phone"), user = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A")), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```